# Supremum vs limit supremum; notation confusion

Tags: limits, notation, supremum-and-infimum

Suppose we have written
$$\sup_n f_n$$
and
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_n f_n$$

How am I to understand the difference between the two?

Comment: The second one doesn't parse: $\sup_n f_n$ doesn't depend on $n$ anymore. Perhaps you mean $\lim_{N \to \infty} \sup_{1 \le n \le N} f_n$ (which, by the way, is not the limit supremum).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid confusion, it is best to write
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty} f_n
\tag{1}$$
and never write
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_n f_n
\tag{2}$$
since (2) is just wrong.  Your textbook should have a definition for (1).

Comment: I am sorry, I used the wrong notation, (1) is correct. Still, can you please explain the difference to me?

Comment: Why don't you write down the two definitions from your textbook?  And then evaluate them when $f_n = \frac{1}{n}$, for example.  In this forum, the asker should show his work before expecting answers from us.

Comment: Supremum is the least upper bound. so $\sup_n f_n=1$, while $\limsup_{n\to\infty} f_n=0$, because it is equivalent to the infinum of the set of supremum for all n?